# Store user specific data for each object

Tags: django

If you have eg an app that stores articles and each of these articles can be rated by the user. This rating is not visible to the other users and is user specific (no overall rating) ie each rating of the same article-object needs to be stored for each user.

Currently I do this complete crazy stuff:

```
class Article(models.Model):    
    text = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.text


class UserArticleStorage(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                null=True,
                                )

    articles_rated_1 = models.ManyToManyField(
        Article,
        related_name="articles_rated_1",
        blank=True
    )
    articles_rated_2 = models.ManyToManyField(
        Article,
        related_name="articles_rated_3",
        blank=True
    )
    articles_rated_3 = models.ManyToManyField(
        Article,
        related_name="articles_rated_3",
        blank=True
    )
```

And I get them in the view by e.g. `request.user.userarticlestorage.articles_rated_3`

What is the normal way to store this user specific rating as an IntegerField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do that by defining a simple model:

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, ..., related_name='ratings')
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,, ..., related_name='ratings')
    rate = models.IntegerField()
```

and then access ratings by:

```
request.user.ratings
```